# Scroll bar when using <object>

Tags: html, scrollbar

I'm trying to use a html file within another file. Posts have said to use , which works but shows with a scroll bar as you can see here www.greensourcehosting.com.

Any ideas on how to get rid of the scroll bar and have it showing full width/height?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Green Source Hosting | Register Domains | Eco-Friendly Web Hosting</title>
<!--[if lt IE 7.]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body scroll="no">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="197" style="background-image:url(images/top-bg.gif); background-repeat:repeat-x;"><table width="950" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="197" valign="top" style="background-image:url(images/top-header.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat;"><table width="950" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><table width="950" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td><img src="images/logo.png" width="263" height="90" alt="" /></td>
                <td><table width="350" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td height="25" align="right" class="topText"><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="#">System Status</a></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="right"><img src="images/call-us.png" width="222" height="54" alt="" /></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="45">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
          <table width="950" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="869"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">Home</a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/divider1.gif" width="2" height="40" alt="" /></td>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">Hosting</a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/divider1.gif" width="2" height="40" alt="" /></td>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">Domain Names</a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/divider1.gif" width="2" height="40" alt="" /></td>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">About Us</a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/divider1.gif" width="2" height="40" alt="" /></td>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">Latest News</a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/divider1.gif" width="2" height="40" alt="" /></td>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">Features</a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/divider1.gif" width="2" height="40" alt="" /></td>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">Guarantees</a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/divider1.gif" width="2" height="40" alt="" /></td>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">Help Center</a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/divider1.gif" width="2" height="40" alt="" /></td>
                  <td class="navText1"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="81" class="whiteText1"><img src="images/login.png" alt="" width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" /> <a href="#">Login!</a></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="1018" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


<object type="text/html" data="http://greensourcehosting.com/maintop/hosting.html">

</object>



  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="background-image:url(images/middle-bg.png); background-repeat:repeat-y;"><table width="925" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="677" height="315" valign="middle" style="background-image:url(); background-repeat:no-repeat;"><table width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="235" height="275" align="left"><img src="images/web-hosting-server.png" alt="" width="235" height="239" /></td>
            <td width="405" valign="top"><table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td><img src="images/powerful-web-hosting.png" alt="" width="312" height="49" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="maintext">We are professionals at providing hosting to indivduals and all type of companies. With us, there is no need for you to need to spend all that money on an expensive dedicated server.</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="21" align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td width="171" class="bluetext"><strong>Unlimited Space</strong></td>
                    <td width="21" align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td width="172" class="bluetext"><strong>Free Setup</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td class="bluetext"><strong>Unlimited Bandwidth</strong></td>
                    <td align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td class="bluetext"><strong>24/7 Support</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td class="bluetext"><strong>Host Unlimited Websites</strong></td>
                    <td align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td class="bluetext"><strong>Eco-Friendly Hosting</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td class="bluetext"><strong>MySQL Databases</strong></td>
                    <td align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td class="bluetext"><strong>Custom Nameservers</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td class="bluetext"><strong>Register Domains</strong></td>
                    <td align="left"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" width="14" height="13" /></td>
                    <td class="bluetext"><strong>No Contract</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><table width="230" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="111"><a href="#"><img src="images/buy-now.png" alt="" width="151" height="51" border="0" /></a></td>
                    <td width="111"><a href="#"><img src="images/learn-more.png" alt="" width="151" height="51" border="0" /></a></td>

                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td valign="top"><table width="245" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="20"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="http://greensourcehosting.com/images/right-image.png" alt="" width="245" height="307" border="0" usemap="#Map2" /></td>
          </tr>

        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      <table width="925" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td height=""></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="925" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <td width="461" align="left" valign="top"><table width="440" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="47" valign="top"><table width="47" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>

                          </table></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                      <td width="10" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" height=""></td>
                      <td valign="top"></td>
                      <td valign="top"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top"><table width="47" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          </table></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                      <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" height=""></td>
                      <td valign="top"></td>
                      <td valign="top"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top"><table width="47" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          </table></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                      <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>

                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>

              </table></td>
              <td width="231" align="left" valign="top"><table width="228" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

</table>
        <tr>
<table width="1018" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="background-image:url(images/middle-bg.png); background-repeat:repeat-y;"><table width="925" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
</table
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href=http://www.freshdesignweb.com/wp-content/themes/fv24/images/icon.ico />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://greensourcehosting.com/table/styles.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" media="all" />
</head>

<div class="container">
            <!-- freshdesignweb top bar -->
            <div class="freshdesignweb-top">
                <span class="right">
                </span>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div><!--/ freshdesignweb top bar -->

     <!-- start header here-->
    <header>

<div id="fdw-pricing-table">
    <div class="plan plan1">
        <div class="header">Enterprise</div>
        <div class="price">$59</div>  
        <div class="monthly">per month</div>      
        <ul>
            <li><b>10GB</b> Disk Space</li>
            <li><b>100GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
            <li><b>20</b> Email Accounts</li>
            <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
        </ul>
        <a class="signup" href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com">Sign up</a>         
    </div>
    <div class="plan plan2 popular-plan">
        <div class="header">Professional</div>
        <div class="price">$29</div>
        <div class="monthly">per month</div>  
        <ul>
            <li><b>5GB</b> Disk Space</li>
            <li><b>50GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
            <li><b>10</b> Email Accounts</li>
            <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
        </ul>
        <a class="signup" href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com">Sign up</a>            
    </div>
    <div class="plan plan3">
        <div class="header">Standard</div>
        <div class="price">$19</div>
        <div class="monthly">per month</div>
        <ul>
            <li><b>3GB</b> Disk Space</li>
            <li><b>25GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
            <li><b>5</b> Email Accounts</li>
            <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
        </ul>
        <a class="signup" href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com">Sign up</a>        
    </div>
    <div class="plan plan4">
        <div class="header">Basic</div>
        <div class="price">$9</div>
        <div class="monthly">per month</div>
        <ul>
            <li><b>1GB</b> Disk Space</li>
            <li><b>10GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
            <li><b>2</b> Email Accounts</li>
            <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
        </ul>
        <a class="signup" href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com">Sign up</a>        
    </div>  
</div>
    </header><!-- end header -->

</div>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/bottom-bg.png" width="1018" height="" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="925" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height=""></td>
<ul class="share-buttons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="share/share.css" type="text/css" />
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgreensourcehosting.com&t=Unlimited%20Eco-Friendly%20Web%20Hosting" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="http://greensourcehosting.com/share/Facebook.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=http%3A%2F%2Fgreensourcehosting.com&text=Unlimited%20Eco-Friendly%20Web%20Hosting:%20http%3A%2F%2Fgreensourcehosting.com" target="_blank" title="Tweet"><img src="http://greensourcehosting.com/share/Twitter.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgreensourcehosting.com" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"><img src="http://greensourcehosting.com/share/Google+.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgreensourcehosting.com&description=Get%20powerful%20web%20hosting%20whilst%20keeping%20emissions%20low.%20Register%20your%20domain%20name%20or%20transfer%20it%20over." target="_blank" title="Pin it"><img src="http://greensourcehosting.com/share/Pinterest.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto:?subject=Unlimited%20Eco-Friendly%20Web%20Hosting&body=Get%20powerful%20web%20hosting%20whilst%20keeping%20emissions%20low.%20Register%20your%20domain%20name%20or%20transfer%20it%20over.:%20http%3A%2F%2Fgreensourcehosting.com" target="_blank" title="Email"><img src="http://greensourcehosting.com/share/Email.png"></a></li>
</ul>
  </tr>
</td>
    <td align="center" class="footerText"><a href="http://greensourcehosting.com">Home</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Web Hosting</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Features</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Why Us</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Guarantees</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Contact Us</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Directory</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Order Status</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Sitemap</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Help Center</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Blog</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Jobs</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#">Testimonials</a><br />
      © Green Source Hosting 2015,  All Rights Reserved  | <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></td>
  <tr>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use an object here when you can just insert the HTML from hosting.html? If that's not possible, how about an iframe?

Comment: Thanks Terwanerik. When I insert the HTML it messes up the format. The layout changes etc. (New to all this by the way). Please could you explain how I could use an iframe? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Was just a case of adding height: 750px. Did try height: 100% but that didn't work